# Find the numbers inside the matrix $D$ in terms of $x$ and $y$

Tags: matrices

Consider the matrix $A$ as follows\begin{pmatrix}
 \sqrt{-xy}&x \\ 
 y&-\sqrt{-xy} 
\end{pmatrix}

where $(x,y)\in\mathbb C^2$

Let $D$ a matrix such that : $D^2=A$

$D$ can be written as follows\begin{pmatrix}
 a&b \\ 
 c&d 
\end{pmatrix}

Find $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: What does $\sqrt{-xy}$ mean?

Comment: What don't you understand ?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the expression $\sqrt{-xy}$. Can you please explain?

Comment: This corresponds to the square root of the product of $-x$ and $y$. But if you want to know why in this matrix there is this square root, it's because when I want to do this exercise for any number, there is this strange case.

Comment: @JotadiolyneDicci  For complex numbers $x,y$, there is no "principal square root" $\sqrt{-xy}$, so $\sqrt{-xy}$ could refer to one of two values. So, you have not completely defined the matrix $A$.

Comment: What do you mean when you talk about **the** square root of $-xy$? Unless $x=0$ or $y=0$, the number $-xy$ has *two* square roots. So, which one of them do you have in mind?

Comment: I'm talking about the positive square root

Comment: @JotadiolyneDicci But there is no **positive** square root when $x,y$ are complex

Comment: I was just talking about the real numbers here. But yes i know that there isn't "positive" in the complex

Comment: @JotadiolyneDicci Okay, so what it seems that you were trying to say is that $\sqrt{z}$ refers to the square root of $z$ that has **positive real part**. And of course, we could say $\sqrt{-1} = i$ (since $z = -1$ is not addressed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course if $x = y = 0$, this is trivial.

In the remaining cases, however, the matrix $A$ satisfies $A \neq 0$ and $A^2 = 0$. As such, there are no matrices $D$ for which $D^2 = A$.

To see that this holds, suppose for the purpose of contradiction that $D^2 = A$. Then, $D$ must have $0$ as its only eigenvalue. Thus, the characteristic polynomial is $\det(D - xI) = x^2$. Thus, by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem we have $D^2 = 0$, contradicting our premise.